Purge Varnish from Magento 2.4.6: laminas error
We did setup Varnish correctly and working fine to cache the files.
However, when Magento try to purge cache on product saving or from cache management, we have the following error:
[2024-04-16T02:27:24.463621+00:00] main.CRITICAL: No cache server(s) could be purged Cache host: 10.0.2.112:80resulted in error message: Deprecated Functionality: strtolower(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($string) of type string is deprecated in /bitnami/magento/vendor/laminas/laminas-http/src/Client/Adapter/Socket.php on line 457 {"method":"POST","url":"https://domain.tld/index.php/admin/admin/cache/massRefresh/","invalidateInfo":{"servers":[{"Laminas\\Uri\\Uri":"//10.0.2.112:80/"}],"formattedTagsChunk":".*"}} []
curl is working fine to reach Varnish.

Looks like php8.1+ compatibility error... Be sure to update all Magento dependencies

Yes, I did but I will check again again. The version used is the latest on the GitHub project.

The issue was a custom code forcing some value before Magento call the lib: plugin for Magento\PageCache\Model\Cache\Server. Fixing this allow to fix the issue without editing the code on vendor side.
Thanks for the help!

You can add the null coalescing operator to this line of code:
$method = strtolower($method);
Replace it with:
$method = strtolower($method ?? '');
For same you can create a Custom patch and apply it using git apply command
Thanks

I did try but Magento doesn't want to use it. I will try to patch the file using composer to make the modification before Magento deploy or compile the code. Thanks you for the code!
